# Using jQuery animate() to increase/decrease current padding

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I am trying to increase/decrease padding-right (+= and -=) of a div on hover and also want an animation effect for that. The below code is doing the job but without animation.

```
    myDiv.mouseenter( function() {
      $(this).css({'padding-right' : '+=35px'});
    });

    myDiv.mouseleave( function() {
      $(this).css({'padding-right' : '-=35px'});
    });
```

P.s., The animate() function is throwing error on using "-=" or "+=" in values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code worked fine in Chrome when I checked....

```
<script> 
      $(document).ready(function () {
         var myDiv = $("#box");
         $("#box").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).animate({
               'padding-right': '+=35px'
            }, 300)
         });

         $("#box").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).animate({
               'padding-right': '-=35px'
            }, 300)
         });
        
      });
</script>

<div id="box" class="box" style="background-color:red; float:left">Test</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Actually I forgot to write it here but have it in the actual code. The code I am looking for is to animate this change

Comment: Look at the changed code in my answer... use `.animate` instead of `.css`

Comment: I tried this one. But it shows error on using += or -=

Comment: Hey thanks! It worked. Idk why but it was throwing error previously when I tried!